# Applescript creating hidden directory and transferring files

Tags: applescript

I was wondering why this script of mine was incorrect. (Note: I am new to AppleScript, so please ignore how terrible it is. :P)

```
set public to "~/Public/"
set p to POSIX path of public
tell application "Finder"
make new folder at p with properties {name:".folder"}
end tell
set sfolder to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
set tfolder to "~/Public/.folder/"
duplicate files of sfolder to tfolder
```

It says there is an error at

```
make new folder at p with properties {name:".folder"}
```

error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all, AppleScript cannot expand a tilde.
- Second of all, the Finder doesn't accept POSIX paths.
- Third of all, the `duplicate`command must be in a Finder application tell block.
- Fourth of all, while the Finder is able to create the invisible folder it cannot copy the files because invisible files are only considered if "Show Invisible Files" is set to true in the preference file which is not reliable.

I recommend to use the shell for the whole task, `ditto` can duplicate the files and create intermediate directories simultaneously.

`POSIX path of (path to public folder)` is the same as `~/Public` but returns the full path. 
I don't know what the two colons stand for, so I just omitted them.

```
set publicSubFolder to POSIX path of (path to public folder) & ".folder"
set myself to POSIX path of (path to me)
do shell script "/usr/bin/ditto " & quoted form of myself & space & quoted form of publicSubFolder
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. I have modified the code a lot. It creates the directory, but when I check in the directory, there is nothing in there. Also, the two colons make it the parent directory of the path to me, according to another post.

Comment: Your code copies in the wrong direction – from ~/Public/.folder to the parent directory of the script. The order of the ditto parameters is source - destination.

Comment: Yup! That works. However, it doesn't copy all of what should be copied in ditto. Does ditto have a limit, or is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: Um, the ditto command works sometimes, but other times, it just copies the scpt file.